# How to deal with existing callback-based library code when using bluebird and promises

Tags: promise, bluebird

I have the following snippet of code which copies a buffer to a local file then when that is successful, it copies it to S3.

However, I don't know how to deal with the callback that the S3 storage function ".send(callback)" requires. I'd like to integrate that in my promise chain also.

```
var writeFile = Promise.promisify(fs.writeFile)
var filename = input + "jpg"

writeFile(archive + "/" + filename, buffer)
    .then(function(){
       console.log("Yay, file written");
       outputs.push(filename);
    })
    .then(function(){
        var body1 = fs.createReadStream(archive + "/" + filename)
        var s3obj1 = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: filename}});
        s3obj1.upload({Body: body1})
        .on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) { console.log(evt); })
        .send(function(err, data) { console.log(err, data) });
    })
```

My intuition would lead me to expect some way of having bluebird's API generate me a nodejs-style callback that allows me to move on with my promises.

I don't seem to be able to promisify the send function.

Thanks

Comment: I dont have a lot of experience with events, but i dont think you can add them to a promise chain the way you are trying to. You may be able to do something like this http://tedkulp.com/2014/08/promisify-events-with-bluebird/

Comment: How did you try to promisify the send function?